# How to turn on IPv6 on an Amazon EC2 instance?

Tags: ipv6, amazon-ec2

Amazon [recently announced](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-public-ipv4-address-charge-public-ip-insights/) they're going to start charging for IPv4 addresses.

How do you tell AWS to allocate an IPv6 address? When I go to my EC2 instance, I see this:

[image]

When I try to change the setting by checking this box:

[image]

I get this error:

[image]

So how do I turn on an IPv6 address for an EC2 instance?

Comment: thank you random person for "fixing" my question, i am forever in your debt.

Answer (score 4):

According to https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/dual-stack-ipv6-architectures-for-aws-and-hybrid-networks/:

1. Go to your VPC settings and assign a /56 prefix.
2. Go to subnet settings within the VPC and assign a /64 to the subnet.
3. Go to the instance's network interface settings and enable IPv6 address assignment.